# How can i get it where if i enter "e" for sales figure and "r" for random? Not able to figure out how

Tags: java, char

```
    int store1, store2, store3, store4, store5;
        char ans = 'e';
        String gen;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randNum = new Random();
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter the sales figure (e) or do you want it randomly generated (r)? ");
        gen=scan.nextLine();
        if (ans == 'e' || ans == 'E')
        {
            System.out.println("Enter todays sales for: ");
            System.out.println("Store 1: ");
            store1=scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Store 2: ");
            store2=scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Store 3: ");
            store3=scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Store 4: ");
            store4=scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Store 5: ");
            store5=scan.nextInt();

            scan.close();

        }
        else 
        {
        System.out.println("Store 1: ");
        store1=randNum.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("Store 2: ");
        store2=randNum.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("Store 3: ");
        store3=randNum.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("Store 4: ");
        store4=randNum.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("Store 5: ");
        store5=randNum.nextInt(10);


        }

    }

}
```

Need to figure out how to get this code working properly. Right now it only recognizes the 'e' and 'E' enter but not if i enter anything else. When it does do the else the random number gen won't work.

Comment: Some help please and don't criticize if some parts are wrong. I'm a beginner in progress

Answer (score 1):

Look at this part of your code

```
gen=scan.nextLine();
if (ans == 'e' || ans == 'E')
```

You are reading in gen, but comparing ans, this can't work.

change your statement to

```
if (gen.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'E')
```

Also, I smell that you are about to compare String, and I smell that you maybe don't know how as you stated *I'm a beginner in progress*.

So note that if you want to compare String, you need to use the `.equals` method as if you use `==` you will compare memory address (as for any other Object)

Comment: what do I need there? when i use ans I get errors on the scan.nextLine(); and am not sure how to fix.

Comment: @squash69 because you try to read a String in a char, use what I posted.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now that is working but when I press (r) for the random number gen. it doesn't generate random numbers?

Comment: @squash69 You need to add a condition for `r`... `if(gen.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'R')`